# Nuxt error.vue on live server not working

Tags: error-handling, nuxt.js

I think I have a rather simple question, but I can't wrap my head around this problem.

Reproduction:

**Localhost:** I made an error.vue in the layouts folder, as mentioned by Nuxt in [their docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views/#error-page). When I go to `localhost/this-is-a-404`, the error.vue file is showing as expected!
[screenshot from the localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBGt9.png)

**Live server:** When I upload my dist (ssr) via FTP, everythings works fine except the error.vue page. Is has no styling and I think it's the default error page for any page.
[screenshot from the live server:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f62b5.png)

error.vue

```
    <template>
    <div class="hero alternate b-white">
        <div class="container">
            <section class="columns hero-top">
                <div class="column is-7 is-offset-1">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="90" height="90" fill="#DBE1EC" viewBox="0 0 48 48" id="error-icon">
                        <path d="M22 30h4v4h-4zm0-16h4v12h-4zm1.99-10C12.94 4 4 12.95 4 24s8.94 20 19.99 20S44 35.05 44 24 35.04 4 23.99 4zM24 40c-8.84 0-16-7.16-16-16S15.16 8 24 8s16 7.16 16 16-7.16 16-16 16z" />
                    </svg>
                    <h1 class="basic-padding-bottom-small"  v-if="error.statusCode === 404">Ooops... <br>Deze pagina bestaat niet!</h1>
                    <h1 v-else>Ooops... <br> er ging iets fout!</h1>
                    <div class="button-group ">
                        <nuxt-link to="/" class="button smoke">
                            Terug naar home
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"
                                stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-chevron-right">
                                <polyline points="9 18 15 12 9 6"></polyline>
                            </svg>
                        </nuxt-link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'NuxtError',
        props: {
            error: {
                type: Object,
                default: null
            }
        },
        computed: {
            statusCode() {
                return (this.error && this.error.statusCode) || 500
            },
            message() {
                return this.error.message || '<%= messages.client_error %>'
            }
        },
        head() {
            return {
                title: this.message,
                meta: [{
                    name: 'viewport',
                    content: 'width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0'
                }]
            }
        }
    }

</script>

<style lang="scss">
    @import "assets/scss/app.scss";

    #error-icon{
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

</style>
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!
Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
generate: {
  fallback: true
}
```

Here's the nuxt explanation about that in the [how to deploy on Netlify](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/netlify-deployment/) page. Even though you're not deploying on Netlify, the issue could be the same.

> For a single page app there is a problem with refresh as by default on netlify the site redirects to *"404 not found"*. For any pages that are not generated they will fallback to SPA mode and then if you refresh or share that link you will get Netlify's 404 page. This is because the pages that are not generated don't actually exist as they are actually a single page application so if you refesh this page you will get a 404 because the url for that page doesn't actually exist. By redirecting to the 404.html Nuxt will reload your page correctly in SPA fallback.
>
> The easiest way to fix this is by adding a generate property in your nuxt.config and setting fallback: true. Then it will fallback to the generated 404.html when in SPA mode instead of Netlify's 404 page.

---

Also, I wouldn't upload my dist folder via FTP, as that would only get the generated stuff to your server. Anything dynamic won't be there.

I recommend having the entire app in the server, preferably with a version control (git). Also, if you have a pipeline built in place where you're always auto deploying a certain branch, it would make your life much easier.

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick for me! Also, I'm quite a nood so I don't know how to deploy a version control on my server, but I'll look into it ;)